# Python pandas spending excessive time in garbage collection

Tags: python, pandas, garbage-collection, performance-testing

I am working on a complex piece of python code which is spends aroubd 40% of the execution time in garbage collection.

```
 ncalls    tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

 **6028  494.097    0.082  494.097    0.082** {built-in method gc.collect}

 1900  205.709    0.108  205.709    0.108 {built-in method time.sleep}

  778   26.858    0.035  383.476    0.493 func1.py:51(fill_trades)
```

Is there a way to reduce the number of calls to gc.collect? I tried gc.disable(), but it's effectiveness is limited as Cpython largely uses reference counting. I am using python 3.6.

Comment: Can you post some of the code? It's hard to say why your code is triggering garbage collection so frequently without seeing it, or a reproducible example that is analogous enough to your real code.

Comment: I am not manually calling gc.collect. This is the output of pstats. The code is too big to be posted here. The code heavily relies on objects.

Comment: I would be surprised if anyone is able to answer this without seeing any of your code. Questions with a [mcve] are much more likely to get an answer. Especially something complicated like this.

Comment: "Heavily relies on objects". That's why the garbage collector is working so hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem, where my code was spending 90% of time in garbage collection.  My function took about 90ms per call in testing, but closer to 1s per call in production.  I tracked it down to pandas checking for a quiet form of its `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

In my case I created a slice of a dataframe like `df = pd.DataFrame(data)[fieldlist]` and then assigned a new column `df['foo'] = ...`.   At this point `df._is_copy` shows that we have a weakref to the original dataframe, so when we call [__setitem__](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3347) it tests [_check_setitem_copy](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L3235) which then does a full garbage collection cycle to kill of the weakref [gc.collect(2)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html).

In production my code is trying to call that function a couple of times per second, with a bunch of large objects (dicts) in a cache, so the garbage collection cycle was very expensive.  Fixed by making sure I didn't create a copy in the first place, and performance increased almost 15x :-|

Comment: Updated references for [`__setitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L3945) and [`_chec_setitem_copy`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/generic.py#L4167)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible to answer properly without seeing the code. There are some generic tips you can use to improve the situation though.

The main one is: Limit the number of allocations. Are you constantly repacking some values in tiny wrappers which aren't useful? Are you copying parts of your strings a lot? Are you doing a lot of message parsing which copies data? Find what allocates memory most often and improve it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler may be helpful here.

Situation-specific fixes:

- Are you doing a lot of math-intensive operations? Maybe moving to something like `numpy` would help since you can use real, mutable, typed arrays rather than lists.
- Do you have a lot of data processing code? You may be able to annotate types on it and compile the module using `cython` to remove the need of wrapping values into python objects.
- For raw memory (parsing / file processing / ...) you can save some allocations by using `memoryview`s: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews

And finally - are you sure the collect time is that problematic? From the trace, you can see that the second place on the list is `time.sleep`. If your `gc.collect` takes 40% of runtime, then `time.sleep` takes 16% - why don't you trigger collection at that point instead? You're explicitly sleeping anyway.

Edit: Also, I do believe you're calling `gc.collect` explicitly somewhere. The call does not appear on `pstats` output automatically. To find out where, try:

```
your_pstats_object.print_callers('gc.collect')
```

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestions. gc.collect() was called by pandas. After some search I found that explicit call to gc.collect in pandas can be disabled by pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)